# How do i can protect image source with php

Tags: php

For example

`<img src="http://88.158.222.18:81/record/current.jpg" alt="Camera Record JPG"/>`

This camera take 1 picture at 1s

How do i can protect the source . Notice : I have multiple links. I need something like variable or ... ?
I accept any server side solution .Thank you!

Comment: What does it mean `protect the source`?

Comment: I want to hide the source and instead display my domain link.` <img src="http://example.com/img.jpg#id&11232` something like that i think.

Comment: If you are uploading multiple images on record folder on your server you can protect others seeing all your images just by putting an index.html file in record folder.

Comment: Do you mean you want to prevent any one to see what in record folder except your server?

Comment: Images cannot be protected perfectly - at some point the data has to be transmitted to the client and displayed. Even if you could, there are other ways to always win, such as take a screenshot or use a camera to take a photo of the screen.